# Is there a connectivity possible between google firebase and AWS MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-firestore

I have data getting stored in Google firebase (i.e. output of google vision API). I need the same data to get stored in MongoDB which is running on AWS. Is there a connectivity possible between Google cloud and AWS for data migration?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for what you're trying to accomplish. Currently Firestore supports exporting it's data as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data) though the format of the export is probably not something MongoDB could import right away. Even if the format was compatible you would need some kind of data processing pipeline to handle the flow from side to side.

Depending on how you're handling the ingestion of Vision API results you might be able to include code to also send that data to MongoDB. If that's not the case you might need to design a custom solution for this particular use case.